# cannot set a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making a blog reader app. Everything works fine until I try to access the detailView from a cell. I receive this error,

`[UINavigationController setPFeedURL:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7f96d5802800`

below code is in the PRTableViewController.m

```
#import "PRTableViewController.h"
#import "PRFeedPost.h"
#import "PRDetailViewController.h"
```

This is where the code is where the crash happens

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PRFeedPost *feed_Post = [self.polisenFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [segue.destinationViewController   setPFeedURL:feed_Post.url];
    }
}
```

This is to help you understand what I am trying to setPFeedURL to. Also in PRViewTableController.m

```
  self.polisenFeed = [NSMutableArray array];

  NSArray *polisenFeedArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *postDictionary in polisenFeedArray) {
    PRFeedPost *fp = [PRFeedPost feedWithTitle:[postDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    fp.author = [postDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];
    fp.thumbnail = [postDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    fp.date = [postDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
    fp.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[postDictionary objectForKey:@"url" ]];
    [self.polisenFeed addObject:fp];

}
```

Now the PRDetailViewController.h,

This is where the property is I am trying to set is,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *pFeedURL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Here is the code in PRDetailViewController.m,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.pFeedURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this is crashing. I know it has to do with this line ,

```
  [segue.destinationViewController   setPFeedURL:feed_Post.url];
```

(at leaset I think it is that line. I can't figure out why I cannot set it.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Thanks for your reply techloverr but the error I get is "no visible interface for UIViewController declares the selector setPFeedURL"

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change This

```
PRDetailViewController *objPRDetailViewController = (PRDetailViewController *)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController]; 
objPRDetailViewController.pFeedURL=feed_Post.url;
```

And Also put bellow code in viewDidAppear

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.pFeedURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: `segue.destinationViewController.pFeedURL=feed_Post.url;` is **identical** to `[segue.destinationViewController setPFeedURL:feed_Post.url];` so it won't solve his issue. His problem is that the destination view controller is a `UINavigationController`, but he thought it'd be his custom view controller.

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of posting corrections as comments.

Comment: Thanks Ashish Thummar! That did the trick. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[[((id)segue.destinationViewController) topViewController]   setPFeedURL:feed_Post.url];
```

let me know if it works

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I answered in the wrong section. It didn't work, I am going home soon to try what the others have proposed. Thanks again for the help.